# ggplot2 facet margin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use `facet_wrap` to plot some data. Here is an example:

```
library (ggplot2)
library (reshape)

# generate some dummy data
x = seq(0,1,0.05)
precision = sqrt(x)
recall    = 1 - precision
fmeasure  = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

# prepare it for plotting
df = data.frame(x=x, precision=precision, recall=recall, fmeasure=fmeasure)
df = melt(df, id.vars=c(x))

# plot it
p = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value, group=variable))
p = p + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~variable, ncol=3)
p = p + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1)) # second plot is without this line
print (p)
```

Figure 1: Plot for above code.
[image: Plot with xlim and ylim]

However, what you see in Figure 1 is that the first and last labels of consequent facets overlap. This could be fixed by increasing the space between facets. Other option is to remove `xlim` and `ylim` ranges as depicted in Figure 2, but this keeps unnecessary space in the facet itself.

Figure 2: Plot with line `p = p + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))` removed.
[image: Plot without xlim and ylim]

I have tried to increase the space between the facets, but so far I have been unable to do it. Do you have any advice?

I use ggplot2 version 0.9.1 .

Comment: for 0.9.1 use: `p + opts(panel.margin = unit(2, "lines")) ` but you have a lot of extra white space and IMO lose so of the effect of the faceting (note 0.9.2 now uses `theme` instead of `opts`)

Comment: I threw it down as an answer.  Wasn't sure if that was what you were after.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker. Yes, this was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for 0.9.1 use: `p + opts(panel.margin = unit(2, "lines"))` but you have a lot of extra white space and IMO lose some of the effect of the faceting (note 0.9.2 now uses `theme` instead of `opts`)

Over the years the ggplot2 API has changed, as of 2018-02-01 this is the updated solution:

```
p + theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))
```

Comment: panel.margin is deprecated (2.2.1), for `panel.spacing`

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Tyler's answer, you can further squeeze the facet panels together using the `strip.text` theme parameter as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

mpgTidy <- pivot_longer(mpg, c(cty, hwy), names_to="mpg_categ", values_to="mpg")

g <- ggplot(mpgTidy, aes(x=displ, y=mpg, color=factor(cyl))) +
  facet_wrap(~ mpg_categ) +
  geom_point()

g
```

[image]

```
g + theme(strip.text=element_text(margin=margin()),
          panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

This can be useful when facet labels are long or include newlines and the faceted plot has both rows and columns.